# Overriding ActiveRecord constructor in Rails "undefined method `stringify_keys'" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to override the constructor for an ActiveRecord object. I want to have the option of passing in a parameter at construction, like this

```
token = LinkedinToken.new("these_permissions")
```

but I get the error message

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for "these_permissions":String
```

Here is my class

```
class LinkedinToken < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :permissions,
              :access_token,
              :access_secret,
              :last_updated

  belongs_to :linkedin_info

  def initialize(perms = nil)
    super
    permissions = perms
  end
end
```

Note: I get the same error if I remove the second line in the constructor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14456713/2622934).  `stringify_keys` is a Hash method.  When you call `super` ActiveRecord thinks you're initializing the object with a hash, like `LinkedinToken.new(my_key_value: "these_permissions")`.